# Filter a column name as a variable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame where my column name will be selected dynamically depending on the week that we currently are so I created a variable for each of the column names:

```
var_wk1 = 'WEEK1'
var_wk2 = 'WEEK2'
var_wk3 = 'WEEK3'
var_wk4 = 'WEEK4'
```

this will be the data frame:

```
data = {'WEEK1':[-5, 0, 5,10],
        'WEEK2':[-10, 10, 0, 5],
        'WEEK3':[0, 0, 5,0],
        'WEEK4':[-5, 0, 5,10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   WEEK1 |   WEEK2 |   WEEK3 |   WEEK4 |
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|      -5 |       0 |       5 |      10 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|     -10 |      10 |       0 |       5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       0 |       0 |       5 |      10 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      -5 |       0 |       5 |      10 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to filter one column and the trick here is to filter the column with the variable instead of the column name, this code works filtering the column name:

```
filter = df[df['WEEK2'] == 0]

   WEEK1  WEEK2  WEEK3  WEEK4
0     -5      0      5     10
2      0      0      5     10
3     -5      0      5     10
```

but I need something working like this, putting the variable name instead of the column name and I have an error with the code:

```
filter = df[df[var_wk2] == 0]
```

Comment: Same for me.  Can you post your error?

Comment: `df.loc[df[var_wk2]==0]`?....also don't assign anything to `filter` function

Comment: Good point.  [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) is a builtin function, so you should call your variable name something else, like `df_filter`.

Comment: somehow in a huge data frame where not working but now is working with this:
filter = df[df['' + var_wk2 + ''] == 0]

Comment: the data in dictionary and printed after creating dataframe is different in the question you have made the columns into rows

Answer (score 1):

You created the wrong dataframe. If you want to create dataframe like below:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   WEEK1 |   WEEK2 |   WEEK3 |   WEEK4 |
+=========+=========+=========+=========+
|      -5 |       0 |       5 |      10 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|     -10 |      10 |       0 |       5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       0 |       0 |       5 |      10 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      -5 |       0 |       5 |      10 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

You should use this code:

```
data = {'WEEK1':[-5, -10, 0, -5],
    'WEEK2':[0, 10, 0, 0],
    'WEEK3':[5, 0, 5, 5],
    'WEEK4':[10, 5, 10,10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```